# Why can't I call property_exists on stdClass?

Tags: php, object, field, stdclass

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$madeUpObject = new \stdClass();
$madeUpObject->madeUpProperty = "abc";

echo $madeUpObject->madeUpProperty;
echo "<br />";

if (property_exists('stdClass', 'madeUpProperty')) {
    echo "exists";
} else {
    echo "does not exist";
}
?>
```

And the output is:

**abc
does not exist**

So why does this not work?

Comment: Because the made up property isn't defined in `stdClass`, but `$madeUpObject`?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Isn't $madeUpObject an instance of stdClass?

Comment: Sure, but setting a property on an instance is not going to change the class definition, is it?

Comment: @Pekka웃 When you do not have a property in a class but access $instanceOfThatClass->nonExistingProperty, a public field is generated by php.

Comment: Yes but not in the class definition of `stdClass`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
if( property_exists($madeUpObject, 'madeUpProperty')) {
```

Specifying the class name (instead of the object like I have done) means in the `stdClass` definition, you'd need the property to be defined.

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/Jd9vXp) that it prints:

```
abc
exists
```

Comment: So $madeUpObject is an instance of class madeUpObject ?

Comment: No, it's an instance of `stdClass`. You're setting a property dynamically (which isn't specified in the class defintion of `stdClass`). That's why you can't specify the class name as a string to `property_exists()`. You need to give it the newly created object, since that object is the only thing that has the newly created property.

Comment: Interesting. So the class does not have the field, but the object does.. Thanks.

Comment: I came to this article just to realize that I have been using the call arguments in the wrong order!

Answer (score 5):

Because `stdClass` does not have any properties. You need to pass in `$madeUpObject`:

```
property_exists($madeUpObject, 'madeUpProperty');
```

The [function's prototype](http://php.net/property_exists) is as follows:

```
bool property_exists ( mixed $class, string $property )
```

The `$class` parameter must be the "class name or **an object of the class**". The `$property` must be the name of the property.

Comment: So madeUpObject is an instance of class madeUpObject?

Comment: No it's an instance of `stdClass`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're concerned about NULL values, you can keep it simple with [`isset`](http://php.net/isset).